# How to determine which rounding method is used internally by BigDecimal.round() in java

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I am using BigDecimal to round an input based on desired significant figures, actual input and desired significant figures comes from a JtextPane. This is the sample code;

```
String input = "1234.56";
String sf = "3";
String ans;
BigDecimal decRep = new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble(input));
decRep = decRep.round(new MathContext(Integer.parseInt(sf)));
ans = String.valueOf(decRep.doubleValue());
System.out.println(ans);
```

This will result to `1230.0` which is well and fine. But it also required to output if it rounded down or if it rounded up.

Is there a way to determine so?

Comment: Just have a look at the constructor of MathContext you are using and you will see that it internally calls another constructor: `this(setPrecision, DEFAULT_ROUNDINGMODE);` then have a look at what `DEFAULT_ROUNDINGMODE` is and you have your answer: `private static final RoundingMode DEFAULT_ROUNDINGMODE = RoundingMode.HALF_UP;`

Comment: See the [JavaDocs of `MathContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html)... It will use `HALF_UP` if you don't provide any specific `RoundingMode`...

Comment: Does it change dynamically? When I tried it, it always shows "HALF_UP" even though it actually used floor round for the current given number. HALF_UP is a rounding mode that both includes round up if greater than or equal to 5 and round down when less than 5 which is the normal one. I want to know if it rounded up or if it rounded down in respect to this rule.

Comment: Please provide an example, my guess would be that your use of `double` as the intermediate value muddies the water, because that introduces the imprecision of the double data type. Why are you using `Double.parseDouble` at all? You should be using the input string directly using `new BigDecimal(input)` instead.

Comment: @Tyro it didn't use HALF_DOWN in your example. You simply sayd you want it rounded after 3 places and the 4th number is a 4 -> gets rounded down to 0. If you change your number to `String input = "1235.56"` you will see the result is `1240.0` because now the 4th number is 5 and therefor gets rounded up. To me it sounds more like your problem is that you expected the round method with `new MathContect(3)` to round after 3 decimal places or something like that.

Comment: If you want to round off after xx decimal places, you can just change the scale  of your BigDecimal directly: `BigDecimal scaledDecRep = decRep.setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);` will produce a BigDecimal with the value `1234.6` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find out whether a value was rounded up or down in respect to its original value. This would be the easiest way to do that:

```
public BigDecimal roundAndLog(String input, String sigFigs) {
  BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(input);
  BigDecimal decimalRounded = decimal.round(new MathContext(Integer.parseInt(sigFigs)));

  int compared = decimalRounded.compareTo(decimal);
  if (compared == -1) {
    System.out.println("Rounded down!");
  } else if (compared == 0) {
    System.out.println("Value didn't change!");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Rounded up!");
  }
  return decimalRounded;
}
```